# Program does not suppress integers, although float numbers are suppressed

Tags: c

I have a txt file like that:

```
alter_ego,simulation,pc,1985,0,0.03,0.03,5.8
simcity,simulation,pc,1988,0,0.02,0.03,2.2
doom,shooter,pc,1992,0.02,0,0.03,8.3
star_wars:dark_forces,shooter,pc,1994,1.09,0.77,1.95,7.7
battle_arena_toshinden,fighting,ps,1994,0.39,0.26,1.27,6.3
resident_evil,action,ps,1996,2.05,1.16,5.05,9
```

using this code, I write in another file like this:

```
alter_ego
simulation
pc
1985
0
0.03
0.03
5.8
simcity
simulation
pc
1988
0
0.02
0.03
2.2
doom
shooter
pc
1992
0.02
0
0.03
8.3
star_wars:dark_forces
shooter
pc
1994
1.09
0.77
1.95
7.7
...
```

however, when the program reaches an integer, it does not write that number to the file.(
for example, the 9 files at the end of the resident evil are not printed.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char line[128];
    char word[32];
    FILE *in, *out;
    int line_length;

    in  = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    out = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    while(1==fscanf(in, "%[^\n]%n\n", line, &line_length)){//read one line
        int pos, len;
        for(pos=0;pos < line_length-1 && 1==sscanf(line + pos, "%[^,]%*[,]%n", word, &len);pos+=len){
            fprintf(out, "%s\n", word);
        }
    }
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

how can I fix it?Thanks...

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the right things here? Do you know for a fact whether there is a newline character `\n` at the end of that line? Or may it actually be the end of the file directly after the `9`?

Comment: No, the file content consists of 100 lines like this. This is not the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> pos < line_length-1
> ```

is wrong - it is omitting last character. Just:

```
pos < line_length
```

Tested with:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdio.h>

char str[] = 
"alter_ego,simulation,pc,1985,0,0.03,0.03,5.8\n"
"simcity,simulation,pc,1988,0,0.02,0.03,2.2\n"
"doom,shooter,pc,1992,0.02,0,0.03,8.3\n"
"star_wars:dark_forces,shooter,pc,1994,1.09,0.77,1.95,7.7\n"
"battle_arena_toshinden,fighting,ps,1994,0.39,0.26,1.27,6.3\n"
"resident_evil,action,ps,1996,2.05,1.16,5.05,9\n";

int main(void){
    char line[128];
    char word[32];
    FILE *in = fmemopen(str, sizeof(str), "r");
    FILE *out = stdout;
    int line_length;

    while (1 == fscanf(in, "%127[^\n]%n\n", line, &line_length)) {//read one line
        int pos, len, r;
        for (pos = 0; pos < line_length &&
                    1 == sscanf(line + pos, "%31[^,]%*[,]%n", word, &len);
                pos += len){
            fprintf(out, "%s\n", word);
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c == ',' || c == '\n')
            printf("\n");
        else
            printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

in file.txt

```
alter_ego,simulation,pc,1985,0,0.03,0.03,5.8
simcity,simulation,pc,1988,0,0.02,0.03,2.2
doom,shooter,pc,1992,0.02,0,0.03,8.3
star_wars:dark_forces,shooter,pc,1994,1.09,0.77,1.95,7.7
battle_arena_toshinden,fighting,ps,1994,0.39,0.26,1.27,6.3
resident_evil,action,ps,1996,2.05,1.16,5.05,9
```

then run command:

```
gcc -o print print.c

./print < file.txt
```

That's all.